# Multiplying with Polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

In $(3xy)^2$, do I distribute that power of two to each of the terms?

$(3^2)\times(x^2)\times(y^2) = 9x^2y^2$?

Or do I just treat it as $3xy^2$?

Comment: The first option.

Comment: $ 3^2 \cdot x^2 \cdot y^2 \; = \; 9x^2y^2 $

Comment: you have computer so search it up. on google

Comment: I am searching it up, right here. ._.

Answer (score 6):

$$(3xy)^2 = (3xy)(3xy) = 3\cdot 3\cdot x\cdot x\cdot y\cdot y = 3^2x^2y^2=9x^2y^2$$

Comment: you got it first

Answer (score 1):

All terms.  $(3xy)^2=(3xy)(3xy)=(9x^2y^2)$

Good time to note how it's important to put those parentheses around expressions like this to distinguish $(3xy)^2$ from $3xy^2$